# Datatables add multiple child-rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table hooked up to the jQuery datatable. Based on this [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) I want to add "hidden" child rows to show extra information.

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgotLfz/1/) where I have a name/value pair.

```
<tr data-child-name="Name1" data-child-value="Value 1">
    <td class="details-control"></td>
```

```js
function format ( name, value ) {
    return '<div>' + name + ': '+ value + '</div>';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({});

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(tr.data('child-name'), tr.data('child-value') )).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
```

My question is how do I add more than one name/value pair? So that I can define various rows like in the datatables.net example.

My source is a php-script that generates html like in the jsfiddle example.

It's probably an easy task but my jQuery skills are very limited :-)

Thank you.

**UPDATE**:
The data comes from an ldap query:

```
$ldapResults[$i]
echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($ldapResults[$i]['sn'][0]) . "</td>"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep data attributes for your data source, you can do something like this

```js
function format ( dataSource ) {
    var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    for (var key in dataSource){
        html += '<tr>'+
                   '<td>' + key             +'</td>'+
                   '<td>' + dataSource[key] +'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
    }        
    return html += '</table>';  
}

$(function () {

      var table = $('#example').DataTable({});

      // Add event listener for opening and closing details
      $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var row = table.row(tr);

          if (row.child.isShown()) {
              // This row is already open - close it
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              // Open this row
              row.child(format({
                  'Key 1' : tr.data('key-1'),
                  'Key 2' :  tr.data('key-2')
              })).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
          }
      });
  });
```

```css
 td.details-control {
    background: url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Item 1</th>
            <th>Item 2</th>
            <th>Item 3</th>
            <th>Item 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-key-1="Value 1" data-key-2="Value 2">
            <td class="details-control"></td>
            <td>data 1a</td>
            <td>data 1b</td>
            <td>data 1c</td>
            <td>data 1d</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-key-1="Value 1" data-key-2="Value 2">
            <td class="details-control"></td>
            <td>data 2a</td>
            <td>data 2b</td>
            <td>data 2c</td>
            <td>data 2d</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Freeez hi and thank you - a further question: what if you want another child in the child?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon can you be more specific please ?

Comment: thank you i meant, what if you want a sub heading within a subheading which shows a bunch of records (rather than listing key value paris)?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon You managed to add a child row within a child row, I am looking to do it that way?

Comment: @JohnDoe it's been five years! I have no recollection of the original code :P, but am certain some sort of solution can be found

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of the data you need to show for each row

EG :

```
var data = [
  { key1 :'value1', key2 :'value2', key3 :'value3'}, //Row1
  { key1 :'value1', key2 :'value2'} //Row2
];
```

And updated the `format()`

```
function format (index ) {
  var json_data =  data[parseInt(index)];
  var op = '';
  $.each(json_data, function(key, value){
    op +='<div>' + key + ': '+ value + '</div>';
  });
  return op;
}
```

Now just add the index of the array in a custom attribute `<tr data-child-index="1">`

And finally `row.child(format(tr.data('child-index'))).show();`

EDIT : No html changes needed.

Calculate the index dynamically using jQuery `index()`

`row.child(format($('#example td.details-control').index($(this)))).show();`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgotLfz/5/)

Comment: the data comes from an ldap query: $ldapResults[$i] 
echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($ldapResults[$i]['sn'][0]) . "</td>"
I can't modify this at the moment.

Comment: I did not understand. So what in the above code you cannot edit??

Answer (score 0):

If are are getting json data to show as child then try it like,

```
else {
    // Open this row
    // pass your json data to show in details
    row.child( format(myJsonData)).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
}
```

And in the format function change it like,

```
function format ( json ) {
    var $json=$.parseJSON(json);// if not parsed
    var str='';
    $json.each(function(key,value){
       str += '<div>'+key+':'+value+'</div>';
    });
    return str;
}
```